# Converting Columns to Rows with two summary values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dcast

I have a data.frame like this:

```
P   Stat    V   Points
1   Goals   2   10
1   Assists 1   3
2   Goals   1   5
2   Assists 1   3
```

and I would like to convert it to something like this:

```
P   Goals   Assists Points
1   2       1       13
2   1       1       8
```

Currently I am using dcast, as follows:

`dcast(stats, P ~ Stat, value.var = "V")`, which works just without the "Points". When I add Points in, it starts duplicating the new columns names with _1, _2 etc.

Any help appreciated. This is not a school project, I'm just a curious consultant trying to refresh my statistics skill-set on problem that interests me!

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `dcast` and then add the 'Points' column

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(d1), P~Stat, value.var = "V")[, Points := sum(d1$Points)][]
#     P Assists Goals Points
#1: 1       1     2     13
```

Comment: fascinating. What is the purpose of [ ] at the end?

Comment: @sjhuk  It is just to show the output on the screen

Comment: Sorry - I think I oversimplified the original question. There can be multiple values of "P", therefore the Points column can't just be the sum of Points

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two possibilities to achieve the desired result.

#### Cast with multiple value.vars

The recent versions of `data.table` allow to specify multiple `value.var` as parameter to `dcast()`:

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.10.4 used
dcast(DT, P ~ Stat, value.var = list("V", "Points"))
#   P V_Assists V_Goals Points_Assists Points_Goals
#1: 1         1       2              3           10
#2: 2         1       1              3            5
```

If only one `Points` column is desired, the points need to be added and the unnecessary columns to be deleted. By chaining, this can be done in one statement but isn't very concise.

```
dcast(DT, P ~ Stat, value.var = list("V", "Points"))[
  , Points := Points_Assists + Points_Goals][
    , c("Points_Assists", "Points_Goals") := NULL][]
#   P V_Assists V_Goals Points
#1: 1         1       2     13
#2: 2         1       1      8
```

#### Cast and join

Alternatively, the dcast of `V` and the aggregation of points can be done in seperate steps and the results being joined afterwards:

```
# dcast
temp1 <- dcast(DT, P ~ Stat, value.var = "V")
temp1
#   P Assists Goals
#1: 1       1     2
#2: 2       1     1

# sum points by P
temp2 <- DT[, .(Points = sum(Points)), by = P]
temp2
#   P Points
#1: 1     13
#2: 2      8
```

Now the two results need to be joined:

```
temp1[temp2, on = "P"]
#   P Assists Goals Points
#1: 1       1     2     13
#2: 2       1     1      8
```

or combined in one statement:

```
dcast(DT, P ~ Stat, value.var = "V")[DT[, .(Points = sum(Points)), by = P], on = "P"]
```

The code looks more straightforward and concise than the first variant.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "P   Stat    V   Points
  1   Goals   2   10
  1   Assists 1   3
  2   Goals   1   5
  2   Assists 1   3")
```

Note that `fread()` returns a data.table object by default. In case `DT` is still a data.frame it needs to be coerced to data.table by

```
setDT(DT)
```